# Jenkins build is incorrectly unstable

Tags: java, jenkins

I see that the Jenkins build is unstable - it is marking one of the test case as failed, however the same test case is working fine on my local machine. I have tried from eclipse as well as "mvn test" on the command line, it is all "green" locally.

I am a bit confused on how to go about debugging this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Explore the Jenkins workspace, find the file matching the failing test; this should give you some hints

Comment: Try edit your post with more information, for example, paste the job console log might be more helpful.

Comment: You should also compare the Jenkins server/slave configuration with your machine (JDK and Maven version, environment variables, ...).

Comment: We did not get to the bottom of it, but as a work around we modified the code a bit by changing the method signature, a bit like "refactoring" and that did the trick. The test on Jenkins was working post refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479553) igoring assert statements.

As a workaround you could enable asserations in unit-testing (in JUnit-Preference page).